# Could not resolve com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar, appium-snackbar

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Can you paste your build.gradle (project)?

Comment: How to paste build.gradle sir

Comment: implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

Comment: repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

Comment: Not this one, the other one. Edit your question by adding with build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You just add this line

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

on code segment of your build.gradle (project) file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
      jcenter()
   }
}
```

Comment: implementation 'org.aviran.cookiebar2:cookiebar2:1.1.4' ....Adding this Dependencies Same problem showing me

Comment: I have use this implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'. Work for me.

Comment: Just do one thing put mavenCentral() along with jcenter() in build.gradle (project) file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sliderscreen"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
   android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin- 
    stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 
    'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 
    'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 
    'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'

    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 
    androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            google()
    
        }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
}
```